# Check if 'Key' exists in a hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap with Key and Value being 'String'. I want to check if a particular key exists by ignoring string after '$' in the Key.

Hashmap contains keys as 'acctId$accountId', 'acctId$desc', 'acctId$crncyCode' etc.

```
Iterator itx = uiToSrvFldMapList.entrySet().iterator();
if(uiToSrvFldMapList.containsKey(cellId)){
      String sSrvFld = (String) uiToSrvFldMapList.get("acctId");
      System.out.println("sSrvFld :: " +sSrvFld);
```

Comment: Why dont you just use a stacked map? Something like `Map<String, Map<String,String>>` would make access easier and faster. You could then check for `myMap.get(firstPart).get(secondPart)`. Of course you have to ceck if the first one is not `null`. This would also be better for your running time.

Comment: Use if(uiToSrvFldMapList.containsKey(cellId.split("$")[0])){

Comment: Not easy with this structure, you basically have to do a linear search through the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "acctId$accountId";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\$.*", "");// remove everything after $
    System.out.println(s);
    // do hm.get(s) here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you

```
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("abc$def","ABC");
    map.put("ab","A");
    map.put("de","b");
    String key = "abc$def";
    String s[] = key.split("$");
    if(map.containsKey(s[0]))
        System.out.println("Value is: "+map.get(key));
    else
        System.out.println("cannot find..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that in ***"acctId$accountId"*** you will have the same String both as ***"acctId"*** and ***"accountId"***, you can search for it in the following way:

```
   `Map<String, String> uiToSrvFldMapList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    uiToSrvFldMapList.put("0000$0000", "test"); // just an example
    uiToSrvFldMapList.put("0000$0001", "description"); // just an example
    uiToSrvFldMapList.put("0001$0000", "2test"); // just an example
    uiToSrvFldMapList.put("0001$0001", "2description"); // just an example

    String acctId = "0000"; // the account id string
    if(uiToSrvFldMapList.containsKey(acctId +"$" + acctId)){
       String sSrvFld = (String) uiToSrvFldMapList.get(acctId + "$" + acctId);                            
       System.out.println("sSrvFld :: " +sSrvFld);
       }`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a test program, which shows a way to achieve this functionality:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> uiToSrvFldMapList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uiToSrvFldMapList.put("acctId$accountId", "accid");
        uiToSrvFldMapList.put("acctId$desc", "accdesc");
        uiToSrvFldMapList.put("acctId$crncyCode", "currencyCode");
        uiToSrvFldMapList.put("smthElse$smthElse", "smthElse");

        List<String> valuesContainingKey = valuesContainingKeys(
                uiToSrvFldMapList, "acctId");

        // Returns if the key is contained
        if (valuesContainingKey.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("The key is not contained in the map");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The part of the key is in the map");
        }

        System.out
                .println("All values, where the corresponding key contains the subkey: ");
        for (String s : valuesContainingKey) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param map
     *            Map containing the key-value pairs
     * @param searchString
     *            A String used as a subkey, for which is searched if it is
     *            contained as a substring at the beginning of a key in the map
     * @return List of all Values from the map, whose corresponding key contains
     *         searchString
     */
    private static List<String> valuesContainingKeys(Map<String, String> map,
            String searchString) {
        List<String> containingKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().startsWith(searchString)) {
                containingKeys.add(e.getValue());
            }
        }
        return containingKeys;
    }
}
```

Simply write the method `valuesContainingKeys` (not needed to be static) where you want this functionality. This method will return a list of all values, whose corresponding key contains the string you are looking for. Simply checking `valuesContainingKey.isEmpty()` will return if there is no value, for which the corresponding key begins with the searched key.